# what is Database Transaction Frames?

Tags: database, transactions

I just need to know what is "Database Transaction Frames"?

from the name i am guessing it is my sql transaction statements that are written in frames or some thing like that.
If it this what i am guessing then why write transactions in frames ?

please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a well-known term, so far as I'm aware, so a link to where you read it in the first place would be helpful.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -- The thing is it is the topic given to me by my professor.So I dont know any thing about it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -- i found this link where there is this topic please check and help if you can [link](http://ol.cadfamily.com/teamcenter/mt00321/PerfConsiderationC10.html)